# Laravel Passport Authentication Issues: Always returns unauthenticated

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

After looking through dozens of answers, I still can't find a solution to his issue.

#### Problem

Every time I make an authenticated request, the response is `{"error":"Unauthenticated."}`

#### Routes

Here are the routes I've been testing with.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials;

Route::get('/test', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
})->middleware('auth:api');

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/test2', function (Request $request) {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

#### Setup

I set this project up as the tutorial instructed, and used the `PHP artisan` commands to construct my database. I then began to use Postman test it.

The token is acquired using a `grant_type: password`, client credentials, and user credentials. A `"Bearer " . $token` type is then granted.

#### What I've Done and Tested

I've checked the .htaccess, token expiration date, namespaces, and other common errors. I setup a test function to check my header information. The results are posted below. For some reason, the issue persists. There also aren't any actual errors... No error.log updates, just a response from the API letting me know the user is not authenticated.

```
 array:12 [
    "cookie" => array:1 [
        0 => "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkwrNGxLOGVtc1M1Y2lYeUMraldTK3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibHRzdVo3bFVJOFhuMDJvZ3RoNEYxK1NsdmhRenZkbmp5b2xuYXVzWTdIUGJ2WGFUbXBiK1JFQ0VNSVlNbjdIbHVmcndmKzBaMzVJbGkxelZFdllhM0E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImZhMDJjZDIwNDgxMTRkMDdjYTBkYmMwODc4YzQ4ZmM3OGFkZTI3NzY1ZDA5NTAyODhkYjRlNTY1OGUyMTYyNGEifQ%3D%3D;  laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Im5hTnVLS3cyc1BzQldudkN2bFNcLzZRPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjIwXC8yRkM3Sk4rWkg0ZFFlaG9RYVErc2ZJT0taSHoxOTU3UVpxejdPZ2MzcHBSc2FCd1NweEZwU2kzQXUxZ1VCVmY1dzZIZldFb2J5QXkwMFwvZmpId1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQxZDIzOGQ0NzllOTg4NmZmZDk2NGI1NDNhMzcwNmI1MWE2MzY0YWIzZTgxZjYzOTAxYjhlMWQ1ZTExNzBiMTEifQ%3D%3D"
    ]
    "accept-language" => array:1 [
        0 => "en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6"
    ]
    "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate, sdch"
    ]
    "postman-token" => array:1 [
        0 => "864e4343-e8f1-2efd-1a75-11660313ba3d"
    ]
    "authorization" => array:1 [
        0 => "Bearer 0dea6edd3f655463c4e19cf26ef10755bcfbff5dcdbe44cd44c1d7a84c250c359c65f064737752e6"
    ]
    "cache-control" => array:1 [
        0 => "no-cache"
    ]
    "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "connection" => array:1 [
        0 => "close"
    ]
    "x-http-proto" => array:1 [
        0 => "HTTP/1.1"
    ]
]
```

#### Suspicions

At this point, I think I just must be using some of the tools wrong. I'm hoping it is a simple mistake, but I'm just completely at a loss as to what it could be.

**(Edit 1) Scope Issues:** Hey, could it possibly be a problem with the `scope` of the tokens?

**(Edit 2) SQL Error** I managed to find an error to work off of. It is a bit odd though.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'api_token' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `api_token` = {AccessToken} limit 1)
```

Comment: Are you sending the field "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" in the headers of the request in Postman?

Comment: @louisfischer - yes, it is a `GET` request. Also, the array posted in my question is the returned header value.

Comment: Same issue, I've upgraded from 5.1 to 5.3 and I can't make passport authentication work. I have done the oauth/authorize and oauth/token queries but it seems that CheckClientCredentials fails to log the user. Trying to get more infos

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this ?

Comment: Yes, but the issue was just that I didn't know how to use this tool properly. I'll go ahead and post the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## My Solution

I actually had a few issues with my program, but even after solving them, I still had errors.

1. My database wasn't set up properly
2. My "Order of Operations" was off. I kept requesting tokens and setting up clients in the wrong order. I thought of my clients as the users, which is incorrect, and a root to many of my issues.
3. I misused the tool in general. I never actually tried to log into the user account, only the client one. This, of course, doesn't make sense, and is why I failed.

So my solution was to stop using Passport altogether.

> What if I still need to get passport working?

Since my solution didn't require me to get passport working, I can only help you so much. When I finally figured out how to authenticate was the second I realized I didn't need it...

1. Make sure your database is set up properly. You can test this by making your own database calls inside your router for debugging. Ensure you can access all the required fields.
2. Use clients properly. I was trying to use clients like they were users because I thought this was the best way to implement a token API. It is not. Make sure you have users accounts set up already, and treat clients as a "Window" that can be climbed through by the application, third-party, etc. Maybe take a step back and plan it out a bit more.

> What if I don't need to get passport working?

If you're in the same boat as me, and it is actually best to stop using Passport, then I suggest going with the basic auth inside Laravel. It is easy to setup, and won't take long to learn.